# To get all tel tag from any web page in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am new to java script. How could I get all tel tag from any web page that is opened in chrome web browser? For example: web page might contain any number of tel tag like this - `<a href="tel:+919911111111"></a>.` so how should I get them using java script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) with this:

```
var telLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="tel:"]');
```

...and then use the `NodeList` in `telLinks`.

That uses an [attribute starts with](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) selector (`^=`) to look for `a` elements whose `href` starts with `tel:`.